How to force an alert check in Prometheus?
Just like in Nagios we have "reschedule check" in order to not wait for 10min for the check to run in order to see if what we did fixed an issue - is there a similar operation in Prometheus ?
I have an alert, that takes a while after it re-check and becomes green

The frequency of Alert evaluation appears to depend on the range of the alert query: https://docs.sysdig.com/en/docs/sysdig-monitor/alerts/alert-types/prometheus-alerts/
To drop the evaluation to 1 minute, you must drop the range of the alert query to <= 3 hours

so what you're saying, is that there's no "button to click on" to request a one-time check for "right now" i need to change the config, then bring it back ?
